# WPF - cannot open a file from local machine in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, wpf, compilation, webbrowser-control

I am currently developing a HTML Editor with C#, which has a preview option, but it doesn't Compile...
And here is my code:

```
        string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();//get TEMP folder location
        tempPath += "htmldev\\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
        }
        tempPath += "current.html";
        if(File.Exists(tempPath))
        {
            File.Delete(tempPath);//delete the old file
        }
        StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(tempPath);
        sr.WriteLine(textHtml.Text);//write the HTML code in the temporary file
        sr.Close();
        previewBrowser.Source = new Uri(tempPath);//When I comment this line my program compiles successfully, and the file is created.
```

I also tried using the Navigate() method, but it didn't work too.

I didn't get any errors or warnings.
edit:If I try to open a website, like google.com it works.

Comment: It doesn't compile but you don't get any errors or warnings? What?

Comment: Where is previewBrowser's declaration ?

Comment: What part doesn't work? The saving of the file of the displaying of the file?

Comment: The file saves properly, and can be viewed with IE or chrome, but if I try to load it in the webBrowser control then try compiling just nothing happens.
declaration...
<WebBrowser x:Name="previewBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="593" Margin="651,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="545" Source="http://www.bing.com/"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your XAML doesn't run properly because `Source="bing.com/"` is not a valid argument for `Uri` constructor (apparently, your code compiles but doesn't run). Just remove `Source` and it should run:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="previewBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="593" Margin="651,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="545"/>
```

If you really need a non-empty `WebBrowser` initially, use `Source="about:blank"` or `Source="http://bing.com/"`.

The following compiles and runs just fine.

**C#**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfWb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                var textHtml = "<html><body><b>Hello</b>, World!</body></html>";

                string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();//get TEMP folder location
                tempPath += "htmldev\\";
                if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
                }
                tempPath += "current.html";
                if (File.Exists(tempPath))
                {
                    File.Delete(tempPath);//delete the old file
                }
                StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(tempPath);
                sr.WriteLine(textHtml);//write the HTML code in the temporary file
                sr.Close();

                previewBrowser.Source = new Uri(tempPath);//When I comment this line my program compiles successfully, and the file is created.
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWb.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <WebBrowser x:Name="previewBrowser"/>
</Window>
```